# Django: disable binary logs for delete() method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a MySQL master-slave configuration and I want to delete some old records on master only and keep them on slave:

```
class MonitorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with connection.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute('SET @@session.sql_log_bin = 0')
            ret = super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
            cur.execute('SET @@session.sql_log_bin = 1')
        return ret

class Monitor(models.Model):
...
    objects = models.Manager()
    nobinlog = MonitorQuerySet.as_manager()
```

The problem with this approach is that now one can do `Monitor.nobinlog.delete()` and this will wipe out the whole table.

I though about `pre_delete` and `post_delete` signals but that will run on each call to `delete()`.

Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to the fact that you usually have to explicitly spell out `Monitor.objects.all().delete()`. You can get that behavior by implementing your manager and queryset separately instead of creating the manager from the queryset with `as_manager`, like this:

```
class NoBinLogQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with connection.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute('SET @@session.sql_log_bin = 0')
            ret = super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
            cur.execute('SET @@session.sql_log_bin = 1')
        return ret

class NoBinLogManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return NoBinLogQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class Monitor(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = models.Manager()
    nobinlog = NoBinLogManager()
```

That doesn't protect you from getting the arguments to `.filter()` wrong and accidentally deleting your data.

If you have a fixed set of conditions, like "records older than 30 days", I would write a utility method instead of creating an extra manager. In this method, you can hard-code the condition. As an additional safety-measure you can add a `dry_run` parameter that will return the records that will be deleted. Something like this:

```
def delete_old_records(dry_run=True):
    kwargs = {'updated_at__lt': now() - timedelta(days=30)}
    if dry_run:
        ret = Monitor.objects.filter(**kwargs)
    else:
        with connection.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute('SET @@session.sql_log_bin = 0')
            ret = Monitor.objects.delete(**kwargs)
            cur.execute('SET @@session.sql_log_bin = 1')
    return ret
```

Depending how you execute this method, consider creating a custom management command.

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to some example how I can do this  by implementing manager and queryset separately as you mentioned?

Comment: `Manager` doesn't have `as_manager()` method and your code is just another approach to my example but thanks.

Comment: @HTF you are right the as_manager was a copy&paste mistake. With this approach, you *can‘t* do Monitor.objects.delete(). I thought that was what you were looking for. If that is not the case, please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes, that's the case but now you can do `Monitor.nobinlog.delete()`. I guess it's kind of workaround to my question.